# java,sorting. Помогите новичку

Tags: java, сортировка

У меня тут проблема одна. Нужно вывести шаги и время сортировки. С временем я справился, но не знаю как сделать шаги. Помогите.

```
class BubbleSort {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  int[] randomNums = new int[20];

    for (int i = 0; i < randomNums.length; i++) {
        randomNums[i] = (int) (100 * Math.random());
    }
    System.out.println("Numbers before sorting: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < randomNums.length; i++) {

        System.out.print(randomNums[i]+" " );

    }
    System.out.println();


    long time = System.nanoTime();
    bubbleSort(randomNums);
    long elapsed = System.nanoTime() - time;
    System.out.println("\nBubble sort time is " + elapsed + " nanoseconds passed, " + elapsed / 1000000000 + " seconds passed");
}

static void bubbleSort(int[] arr) {
    int numbers = arr.length;
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < (numbers - i); j++) {
            if (arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) {
                //swap elements
                temp = arr[j - 1];
                arr[j - 1] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }

        }
    }

}
 }
```

Comment: перед `for (int j = 1...` вставь вывод текущего `i`... если я верно понял, что есть "шаги".

Answer (score 0):

Если под шагами подразумевается состояние сортируемого массива на каждом шаге сортировки то выведи после

> arr[j] = temp;

```
System.out.println(arr.toString());
```